# Подскажите, какой тип возвращает функция

Tags: java, generics

Не могу разобраться, какой тип возвращает следующая функция

```
public <D extends DataSource> DataSourceBuilder<D> type(Class<D> type) {
    this.type = type;
    return this;
}
```

Уточню свой вопрос. Пока я начинающий, я привык к такому виду функций

*Модификатор_доступа   Тип_возвращаемого_значения   Название_функции(Параметры)*

Например

```
public List<?> getListOfSomething()
```

Вернет `List` объектов, классы которых наследуются от Object

---

А в примере выше как будто возвращается двойной тип - примерно вот так я вижу

**public** *Тип_Наследник_DataSource Тип_DataSourceBuilder* имя_функции (Параметр)

Как это понять? Двойной тип же не может быть, видимо я неправильно читаю функцию?

Comment: Это дженерик (обобщенный) метод. То что идет в угловых скобках после public - это параметр дженерика, описывает что дальше будет использоваться тип D (который при передаче конкретного параметра в метод станет конкретным типом), и накладывается ограничение на этот тип.

Comment: ну да, верно.   Тип D, с ограничением в виде наследования от DataSource.  А DataSourceBuilder - это что? Тоже какое-то ограничение на тип D?

Comment: `DataSourceBuilder<D>` - это тип возвращаемого значения метода.

Comment: insolor, спасибо! С вашим ответом и поэкспериментировав в IDE понял

Comment: @OlegBokerov, это пример реализации шаблона проектирования "строитель" с "плавным" интерфейсом (когда сеттер возвращает ссылку на текущий экземпляр строителя).

Answer (score 2):

Вкратце:

- `DataSourceBuilder<D>` перед именем метода - это и есть тип возвращаемого значения метода.
- `<D extends DataSource>` перед типом возвращаемого значения показывает, что тут generic (обобщенный) метод, в определении которого далее будет использоваться тип `D` расширяющий тип `DataSource`.

В дальнейшем при использовании метода, когда будет передан конкретный параметр, `D` будет замещен конкретным типом. Т.е., например, если метод будет вызван как `type(SomeDataSource.class)` (где `SomeDataSource` отнаследован от `DataSource`), то у возвращаемого значения будет тип  `DataSourceBuilder<SomeDataSource>`.

Более простой (игрушечный) пример без ограничения типа:

```
private static <T> List<T> singleItemList(T item) {
    return List.of(item);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = singleItemList(1);
}
```

Тут `<T>`, опять же, говорит, что это обобщенный метод, и дальше в определении метода будет использоваться тип `T` (без ограничения, от чего он будет отнаследован).

Дальше при передаче в метод целого числа, итоговый возвращаемый тип станет `List<Integer>`, при передаче строки - `List<String>`, и т.д.